# How to send zipped list in context (Django)

Tags: python, django, list

I am trying to send a zipped list in context to my HTML template. But I'm only seeing the data of the latest object and not all the objects. Document is my model name.

I am trying to scrape a HTML page and the values I've received are being stored in list (I'm using lxml to parse).

Here is the relevant code from views.py

```
query_results=Document.objects.order_by('-id')
zipped=Document.objects.all().distinct().values_list('zipped')
context ={
"query_results": query_results, "zipped": zipped,
}
return render(request, "result.html", context)
```

Here is how I'm displaying the data in my template's table.

```
{% for item in query_results %}
<tbody>
    <tr>
 <td>...</td>
 .
 .
<td colspan="2">
    {% for i,j in zipped %}
        <b>{{ i }}</b> : {{ j }}<br><br>
        {% endfor %}
    </td>
  .
  .
</tr>
</tbody>
{% endfor %}
```

This is how I zipped the two lists.

```
Mymodels=Document()
Mymodels.zipped = zip(Mymodels.anchortext,Mymodels.anchorlink)
```

I'm supposed to get different values for my 3 rows but I'm getting the same value for all the 3 rows. The other values are fine only the zipped values are the same.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is `Mymodels`? What does the `zip` aim to do? can you not just construct your values from the two fields?

Comment: Added some more info to the question. Mymodels is Mymodels=Document(). I'm receiving two lists after parsing using lxml and I want to have a one is to one relationship between those. So the first element of list1 is related to first element of list 2 and so on.